# Redirecting mydomain.previewdns.com to mydomain.com (temporary mode)

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, dns

Godaddy host provides the preview dns service ,i indexed  mydomain.previewdns.com

and it displays a lot of results but it has a lot of problems as you know like not helping ranking for the original domain and also it is not showing my ads..

I tried:

```
RewriteEngine On RewriteBase / RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}
!^http://www.mydomain.previewdns\.com$ [NC] RewriteRule ^(.*)$
http://www.mydomain.com [R=302,L]
```

But this redirect rules redirects correctly in localhost(even am not asking for localhost redirecting)  but when i put it remotely it makes the website offline.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `http` in `%{HOST_NAME}` variable. Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \.previewdns\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.mydomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Bro no errors but redirection not working (still loading the same address)

Comment: Make sure `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` are enabled in above code is placed in `DOCUMENT_ROOT`

Comment: yeah i already have a lot of rules defined in .htaccess and working.

Comment: Then make sure this particular ruleset is before any other existing rule.

Comment: so at present `http://mydomain.previewdns.com` is loading home page of of `http://www.mydomain.com/` ?

Comment: Well that rule is most basic of all rewrite rule and it definitely works. So it is some domain setup issue on your side that you need to figure out for ex: what is DOCUMENT_ROOT for `mydomain.previewdns.com`? Also I am not asking about URL, do you same page content as `http://www.mydomain.com/` when you enter `http://mydomain.previewdns.com` ?

Comment: Also try this in a different browser to avoid caching issues.

Comment: As per GoDaddy `preview URL is www.coolexample.com.previewdns.com` not  `mydomain.previewdns.com`

Comment: Yes I realize that, can you try my edited answer now.

Comment: Ok if you don't mind sharing, what are real domain names? (for my testing)

Comment: Ye it could be the way previewdns is setup.